# If thin timeouts, the instance won't reply anymore

Tags: ruby, nginx, thin

I have this setup:

- Ruby 1.8.7
- Rails 2.3.18
- Three instances of Thin
- Nginx as proxy

It's a high concurrency website. From time to time, there is some request that raises a timeout in one of the thin instances (due to very heavy operations). When this happens, the instance CPU goes to 100%, and stops replying to any new request.

NGinx by default has an option to forward the request to the next upstream, and as the request ends in a timeout, it ends with all three instances using 100% CPU, and not replying to any request.

We have modified this NGinx option to:

```
proxy_next_upstream off;
```

but still have the issue. If a user refreshes the page, it will end up breaking all our thin instances.

- Why does thin keep running at 100% CPU if the request ends in a timeout?
- Is there a way to make thin continue running fine if one of the requests ends in a timeout?
- What would be the best way to automatically restart instances if they are blocked like an Nginx hook that calls a command if it is receiving timeouts?

I know we need to upgrade ruby and rails versions, and I know that heavy operations should be done in the background, but please don't make any comments about that, and stick with my questions.